# How to integrate functions of symbolic variables in GNU Octave 5.1.0

Tags: octave, symbolic-math, integrate

I just downloaded the latest Octave version and the symbolic package which I have already installed and loaded but something is not working.
The code I wrote is formally equal to the one I found [at this link](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/@sym/int.html), so I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

This is the code I wrote:

```
syms r;
b=1/((r^2)*sqrt((r^2)-1));
B=int(b,r);
```

and this is what I found on the command window:

```
Symbolic pkg v2.7.1: "python" isn't recognised as an internal or external command, 
    nor as an executable programm or a file batch.
error: Cannot run the Python executable "python"
    Try "sympref diagnose" for more information.
error: called from
    assert_have_python_and_sympy at line 61 column 7
    python_ipc_popen2 at line 79 column 5
    python_ipc_driver at line 59 column 15
    python_cmd at line 164 column 11
    valid_sym_assumptions at line 38 column 10
    assumptions at line 82 column 7
    syms at line 97 column 13
    provaintegrazione at line 1 column 1
```

Comment: Octave's symbolic package calls python under the hood, and needs python to be installed. Do you have python installed on your system?

Comment: have you followed the installation instructions from the website? https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy

Comment: The error message says 'Try "sympref diagnose" for more information.' Did you do that?

Comment: thank you for the answers! I installed python but it still doesn't work. I am very new to the programming world and I really do not understand what I should do...